# Unexpected Identifier

Tags: javascript, function, identifier

I am not sure where this is occurring. I have tried changing around the code to see if the error would go away but I received other errors.

```
function doesItHit(){
    if(toHit * Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 1 >= enemyEvasion){
        itHits = true
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does this mean `set itHits = true`? Is this new in javascript?

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? It doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks I think I got my train of though mixed in with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write set to asign a value to itHits.

Remove this and the eunexpected identifier error will be resolved.

Don't forget to declare the variables needed

```
    var itHits = false;
    var enemyEvasion = 100;
```

function doesItHit(){

```
if(toHit * Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + 1 >= enemyEvasion){itHits = true}
console.log("itHits: " + itHits);
```

}

[Here is a fiddle to show, that it works.](http://jsfiddle.net/HK22p/)